# Actionscript 3 Injecting string to an existing variable/constant

Tags: actionscript-3, starling-framework

very simple question that I cannot find an answer to:

```
private const LEFT_HOUSE_2_X:Number = 445;
private const LEFT_HOUSE_2_Y:Number = 145;
private const LEFT_HOUSE_2_WIDTH:Number = 45;
private const LEFT_HOUSE_2_HEIGHT:Number = 35;
```

How can I use access the constant above if I am using an iterator:
e.g.

```
var i:uint = 2;

LEFT_HOUSE_{ i }_X ?
```

Also to be done with a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using square brackets you can read a const or variable with variable name

```
this["LEFT_HOUSE_"+i+"_X"]
```